# Using inputs of type "command" in tasks.json

Tags: visual-studio-code, task

Using Visual Studio Code 1.39.2 on Ubuntu 18.04. The [Visual Studio Code documentation for Input variables](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_input-variables) shows an example for selecting a name from a list. By defining an input like this:

```
"id": "pickFromList",
"type": "pickString",
"description": "What folder do you want to create?",
"options": [
    "dirOption1",
    "dirOption2",
    "dirOption3"
],
"default": "dirOption1"
```

It is now possible to use the selection to create a folder in a task:

```
"label": "Create folder by 'pickString' input",
"type": "shell",
"command": "mkdir",
"args": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/${input:pickFromList}"
]
```

Nice! The documentation says there is a general-purpose `command` type, but no example is provided. I tried this, without success, which should have generated a 16-character random string (this works from bash using the command `openssl rand -base64 32 | tr -d /=+ | cut -c -1`):

```
"id": "randomString",
"type": "command",
"command": "openssl",
"args": [
    "rand",
    "-base64",
    "32",
    "| tr -d /=+ | cut -c -16)"
]
```

After hrs of searching, I cannot find a single working example using `command` type input! Does this actually work?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can check the documentation:[docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference).
However, I agree with you since the example that they didn't provide details:

```
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Run specific test",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${input:pickTest}"
    }
  ],
  "inputs": [
    {
      "id": "pickTest",
      "type": "command",
      "command": "extension.mochaSupport.testPicker",
      "args": {
        "testFolder": "/out/tests"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Apparently, the name command is a little bit misleading. It's like a value that you get from your `settings.json` file. Yet, it is possible to use the command input type with extensions to achieve interesting results.